# Dynamic Partial Based on Select Box - Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've edited my request to hopefully be clearer.  I need to render a partial dynamically based on a previous selection box.

REQUEST belongs to PRODUCT

PRODUCT belongs to CATEGORY

CATEGORY has many PRODUCTS

PRODUCT has many REQUESTS

User hits form: create_request.html.erb

User selects a category, then the products select list is populated (like Railscast 88 - dynamic select boxes)

What I now need is to render different partial forms based on which product is selected.  I suck at jquery.

create_request.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "dynamic_products.js" %>

<% form_for :request, :url => {:controller => :requests, :action => :create_request, :id => params[:id]} do |f| %>

  <label>Select Category:</label>
  <%= select( "request", "category_id", Category.find( :all).collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] })%></br>

  <div id="product_field">
   <label>Select Product</label>
   <%= select( "request", "product_id", Product.find( :all).collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] })%></br>
  </div>


  ####  and here is where I need help:
  ####  if request.product_id = 1, render partial _form1
  ####  if request.product_id = 2, render partial _form2

  <button  type="submit">Submit</button>

<% end %>
```

dynamic_products.js.erb:

```
var products = new Array();

<% for product in @products -%>
  products.push(new Array(<%= product.category_id %>, '<%=h product.name %>', <%= product.id %>, <%= product.active %>));
  products.sort()
<% end -%>



function categorySelected() {
  category_id = $('request_category_id').getValue();
  options = $('request_product_id').options;
  options.length = 1;
  products.each(function(product) {
    if (product[0] == category_id && product[3] == 1) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(product[1], product[2]);
    }
  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('product_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('product_field').show();
  }
}


document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  categorySelected();
  $('request_category_id').observe('change', categorySelected);
});
```

Comment: You need to use Ajax, trigger it on the event 'onChange' of the product/service select_box, pass the selected value to Ajax and then render partially the form.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do.  Can you help me with a skeleton method to get me started?  Really appreciate it

Comment: I need more info about the relation between Request / Category / Product (who belongs to who); and possibly how the select_box should be updated (refresh the list of products belonging to the selected category?)

Comment: request has many categories and products.  product belongs to category. category belongs to request.  user selects category, then products selection list gets populated (this is already working).  what I need then is to show different forms based on the product selected.

Comment: I've edited my original post to hopefully be clearer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there fundamental reasons why the partials are different? Can't you render one partial with an if statement to distinguish the output?

Comment: Yes, the forms are completely different, with several different required fields.  I wish it were that easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one reminder first before we start. I'm not sure about this but I think `request` is a reserved word in rails.

**JS**

this just observes the dropdown and performs an ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#request_product_id').change(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: '/products/' + this.value + '/form_partial' });
  });
});
```

**ROUTES**

nothing fancy here either.  Just setting up a route where the ajax will go to when it is triggered

```
resources :products do
  get :form_partial, on: :member
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

we just fetch the product using `:id` which is passed from ajax

```
def form_partial
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
end
```

**JS TEMPLATE**

you need to create a `form_partial.js.erb` which will render the partial depending on the product.  The code below appends the partial after the `product_field` div

```
 # app/views/products/form_partial.js.erb
 $('#product_partial').remove();
 <% if @product.id == 1 %>
   $('#product_field').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('partial1') %></div>');
 <% else %>
   $('#product_field').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('partial2') %></div>');
 <% end %>
```

**UPDATE: for rails 2.x**

we just need to change the routes and the js template in order for this to run on rails 2.x

**ROUTES 2.x**

```
map.resources :products, member: { form_partial: :get }
```

**JS TEMPLATE 2.x**

if I remember correctly, the file should be named `form_partial.js.rjs`.  This will give you a `page` variable which you can use to add js.

```
 # app/views/products/form_partial.js.rjs
 page << "$('#product_partial').remove();"
 page << "<% if @product.id == 1 %>"
 page << "  $('#product_field').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('partial1') %></div>');"
 page << "<% else %>"
 page << "  $('#product_field').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('partial2') %></div>');"
 page << "<% end %>"
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this.  One note, this is Rails 2.3.5, so my routes.rb uses "map.resources ..."

Comment: And, do I need to create a new JS file or can I put the JS in my existing dynamic_products.js file?  I did the latter, but nothing happens when I select the product.

Comment: i've updated my answer. can you try it out?  also, rails 2's default js is prototype. are you using prototype?

Comment: I'm going to try this tomorrow - thank you for your help.  I gave you the bounty and the vote for all your help.  At least I'm pointed in the right direction now.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi out there - where do I put the: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#request_product_id').change(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: '/products/' + this.value + '/form_partial' });
  });
});`

Comment: it should be placed in an asset file (for Rails 3.1 above) or in the view itself.

Comment: Thanks, but this app is on Rails 2.3.5.  Do I put the JS script in the JS template form_partial.js.erb?  I obviously have no idea how to work with JS, and before anyone says I should learn it, I plan to!  ;)  I just need help with this method now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope. it should be placed at the bottom of `create_request.html.erb`

Comment: Thanks - I added it to the view, but get an IE error: `Object doesn't support this property or method.` and the dynamic view does not load.  I'm sorry I'm so lame.

Comment: are you using jquery or prototype?

Comment: Um, how can I tell?  This app was built several years ago using whatever was standard at the time with Rails 2...

Comment: In that case, you're probably using prototype.  Sorry but I don't remember how to use prototype.  You can look at the api here. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/

Comment: No problem - I think it might be time to refactor in Rails 4!  ;)  Thanks for all your help - I really appreciate it.