# Rails render partial depending on value of collection select

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am working on a classifieds based website, and I want to make the form adjust to the type of classified being entered by javascript.

For example I have many types ie. Cars && Mobile Phones

I have three dropdowns that use coffee script to filter based on the previous input (code will be included below).

I want the form to load a partial depending on the selected value in the last box.

Have a look at the example below.

The first dropdown is for category, then sub-category, then sub-sub-category.

I want when the last box "Games" is selected for it to load the partial "_games.html.erb"

[image: an example]

The Coffee Script I have for hiding and filtering the dropdowns is as follows

```
  jQuery ->
  $('#classified_tag_list').autocomplete
    source: $('#classified_tag_list').data('autocomplete-source')


  $('#classified_sub_category_id').hide()
  $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').hide()
  sub_category = $('#classified_sub_category_id').html()

  $('#classified_category_id').change ->
    category = $('#classified_category_id :selected').text()
    options = $(sub_category).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").html()
    if (options)
      $('#classified_sub_category_id').html(options)
      $('#classified_sub_category_id').show()
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').empty()

    else
      if(not category == 'Please select a category')
        $('#classified_sub_category_id').parent().hide()
        $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').parent().hide()
      $('#classified_sub_category_id').empty()
      $('#classified_sub_category_id').empty()
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').empty()
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').empty()




  suburbs = $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').html()
  $('#classified_sub_category_id').change ->
    city = $('#classified_sub_category_id :selected').text()
    options = $(suburbs).filter("optgroup[label='#{city}']").html()
    if (options)
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').html(options)
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').show()
    else
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').empty()
      $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').hide()
```

So how do I use javascript to load the partial depending on the value of the last dropdown?

[EDIT]

I looked at [Dynamic Partial Based on Select Box - Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592642/dynamic-partial-based-on-select-box-rails-2-3-5)

and this is what I have

```
_form.html.erb

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').change(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: '/classifieds/form_partial/'+ this.value });
  });
});
</script>
```

---

```
routes.rb

  resources :classifieds do
    match "/form_partial/:id" => "classifieds#form_partial" 
  end
```

---

```
classifieds_controller.rb

def form_partial
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

---

```
form_partial.js.erb

 <% if @category == 1 %>
   $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('/forms/cars') %></div>');
 <% else %>
   $('#classified_sub_sub_category_id').after('<div id="product_partial"><%= escape_javascript render('/forms/cars') %></div>');
<% end %>
```

---

But that gives the error

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0xa0805fc>:0xb574788>
  (in /home/james/hustle/app/assets/javascripts/form_partial.js.erb)
```

Comment: and whats the question?

Comment: James, see if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592642/dynamic-partial-based-on-select-box-rails-2-3-5

Comment: Hi @LuísRamalho I followed the tutorial but get some errors, as posted in the updated question

Comment: Would you please share the contents of the file where the error occurs `form_partial.js.erb`? Thank you

Comment: @LuísRamalho it is included in the question

Comment: You mean the `format_partial.js.erb` is `form_partial.js.erb`?

Comment: yes sorry, that was a typo

Comment: The error is happening because you're putting the file `form_partial.js.erb` in the assets folder. Try to move to the views folder instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me fixed by Luís Ramalho as per comment

> The error is happening because you're putting the file form_partial.js.erb in the assets >folder. Try to move to the views folder instead. – Luís Ramalho