# Rails display partial based on drop down selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

So I am referencing this to set up what I am trying to do: [Dynamic Partial Based on Select Box - Rails 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592642/dynamic-partial-based-on-select-box-rails-2-3-5)

Based on a product_type I want to dynamically display one of two different partials each containing the remaining form fields.

application.js

```
$('#capsule_project_type_id').change(function() {
      $.ajax({url: '/capsules/form_partial/' + this.value});
}
```

routes.rb

```
get '/form_partial/:id' => 'capsules#form_partial'
```

controller.rb

```
def form_partial
  @project_type_id = ProjectType.find(params[:id])
end
```

form_partial.js.erb

```
<% if @project_type_id == 1 || @project_type_id == 2 %>
  $('#form-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form1', locals: { capsule: @capsule, f: f }) %>");
<% else %>
  $('#form-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'form2', locals: { capsule: @capsule, f: f }) %>");
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb
Creating form:

```
<%= form_for @capsule, multipart: true do |f| %>
...
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :project_type_id, "Project type" %>
<%= f.select :project_type_id, ProjectType.all.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, { :include_blank => "Please select a type..." }, { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>
<div id="form-details">
</div>
```

When I select the dropdown the ajax fires but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007fd298ce71e8>:0x007fd2980a0268>):
    1: <% if @project_type_id == 1 || @project_type_id == 2 %>
    2:   $('#form-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'weddingfields', locals: { capsule: @capsule, f: f }) %>");
    3: <% else %>
    4:   $('#form-details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'showerfields', locals: { capsule: @capsule, f: f } ) %>");
    5: <% end %>
```

I have the variable set in the form_partial however it is not being recognized. Am I not escaping it correctly?

Please advise.

Comment: What r u trying to pass in `{ capsule: @capsule, f: f }` with `f: f` ?

Comment: You need to set `@capsule` in your controller method.

Comment: Did u try like this `<%= j (render partial: 'form1', locals: { capsule: @capsule }) %>`

Comment: I got curious about you config/routes.rb. You map /form_partial/:id and calls /capsules/form_partial/... Do you have some route matching /capsules/form_partial/:id ???

Comment: 7urkm3n those are included because it is nested within the form builder so I need to pass f so the partial forms will generate there labels/fields. I'll try it the way you suggested.

Comment: Ed no I don't however the url seems to resolve correctly per the ajax call.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am still getting the error message. It doesn't recognize the f: f local variable

Comment: I might be wrong but from a brief look, I don't think `<% if @project_type_id == 1 || @project_type_id == 2 %>` can ever be satisfied; `@project_type_id` is assigned to a ProjectType instance, not an Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an odd error considering you have defined `f` in

```
<%= form_for @capsule, multipart: true do |f| %>
```

Are you sure there's not an extra `end` before you reference the `f` variable?

By the way, I'm not sure AJAX is the best approach to this.

Rather, you can put all of the form partials on the page and hide them all
initially with CSS/JS.

Then you can attach Javascript event handlers to your form so that when
an input is selected, it's corresponding form partial is toggled open.

By the way, I find that it is often easier to understand what is going on in a form if you write it by hand instead of using `form_for`. You can see [this tutorial](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/forms).

Comment: Max I agree with you and decided yesterday to use jQuery instead. Less overhead.